# How to export BigQuery data to GCS?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

I'm an Airflow newbie, trying to gather data from BigQuery and export queried data to Google Cloud Storage. I created a task to check whether queried data exist or not:

```
t1 = BigQueryCheckOperator(
    task_id="bq_check_covid_data_exists",
    sql="""
        SELECT COUNT(*) > 0
        FROM bigquery-public-data.covid19_italy.data_by_region
        WHERE DATE(date) = DATE_ADD(DATE "{{ ds }}", INTERVAL -2 DAY)
    """,
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    dag=dag
)
```

Now, I want to query this data and then export to GCS, maybe using [BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_gcs/index.html#module-airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_to_gcs) idk. Which Operators I need to use for this kind of a job? I will be pleased if you provide some code examples, or sources.

Answer (score 1):

You can split this in two steps:

1. BigQuery operator to create a temporary table with your data
2. BQtoGCS operator for storing on cloud storage

First task can be solved as follows:

```
BigQueryOperator(
        task_id="execute_check",
        bigquery_conn_id=google_cloud_connection_id,
        bql=query,
        destination_dataset_table="project:tmp_dataset.table_name",
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        allow_large_results=True,
        dag=dag
    )
```

Then upload on GCS:

```
BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
        task_id="save_data_on_storage",
        source_project_dataset_table="project:tmp_dataset.table_name",
        destination_cloud_storage_uris=["gs://bucket/path/file.csv"],
        export_format="CSV",
        field_delimiter=",",
        print_header=False,
        bigquery_conn_id=google_cloud_connection_id,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

Bonus: setup a `tmp_dataset` (or whatever name) as a temporary dataset in BigQuery with fixed table expiration.

I just end up suggesting how to solve your exact problem but note that may be better ways to understand if a table has (recent) data. For example you can also query table metadata and get information about last partition and then manage this information as you want.